# Android Notifications Cancel

Tags: android

i have been working on android notifications and it works fine. The problem i have is that when i cancel notifications with `manager.cancel()` or `manager.cancel(id)` and another notification arrives, the previously canceled notifications are also shown yet i want them canceled forever, please help. Below is my code.

```
 private void sendNotification(String msg) {


        Intent intent = null;
        if(REQUEST_ID != null)
        {
            intent = new Intent(ctx, PayApp.class)
                    .putExtra("FRAGMENT", "Transactions")
                    .putExtra("REQUEST_ID", REQUEST_ID)
                    .putExtra("NOTIFICATIONID", NOTIFICATION_ID);
        }
        else
        {
            intent = new Intent(ctx, PayApp.class).putExtra("FRAGMENT", "Transactions");
        }

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        counter = notificationCounter.incrementAndGet();
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setAutoCancel(true).setNumber(counter)
                        .setContentText(msg)
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.intel_blue_deeper))
                        .setContentTitle("Xente Agency");

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle(mBuilder);

        inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Xente Agency");
        messageList.add(msg);

       for(String m : messageList)
       {
           inboxStyle.addLine(m);
       }

        mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

And I cancel it from the fragment that it opens on click

```
if(getArguments() != null)
        {
            REQUEST_ID = getArguments().getString("REQUEST_ID");
            NOTIFICATION_ID = getArguments().getInt("NOTIFICATIONID", 0);

            if(NOTIFICATION_ID == 1)
            {
                NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                //this also does not work
                //manager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID)
                manager.cancelAll();
                NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` flag to  instead of `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` flag?

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: there is no such PendingIntent.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL

Comment: @odichdaniel sorry, that's my mistake. please try this 'FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT' flag.

Comment: Let me try and get back to you